# c# databinding modifying grid values

Tags: c#, grid, controls

I have a crud form with a datagridview.
Here's my "refresh" code:

```
private void Recuperar()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string CommandText = "SELECT * from sectores order by sector";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, Variables.Conexion);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.TableName = "sectores";
            adapter.Fill(table);

            grilla.DataSource = table;

            grilla.Refresh();
            grilla.Columns["sector_id"].Visible = false;
            grilla.Columns["clave"].Visible = false;
            grilla.Columns["sector"].HeaderText = "Sector";
            grilla.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            SetDataBinding();

        }

private void SetDataBinding()
        {
            this.textBoxId.DataBindings.Clear();
            this.textBoxId.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", grilla.DataSource, "sector_id"));
            this.tbSector.DataBindings.Clear();
            this.tbSector.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", grilla.DataSource, "sector"));
            this.tbClave1.DataBindings.Clear();
            this.tbClave1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", grilla.DataSource, "clave"));
            this.tbClave2.DataBindings.Clear();
            this.tbClave2.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", grilla.DataSource, "clave"));
        }
```

In the code of my "Add" button, i clear the text of my controls (the controls that are binded to the datagrid), so the user insert the new values.

```
private void btn_agregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grilla.ClearSelection();
            accion = DataRowAction.Add;
            SetEstado();
        }

private void SetEstado()
        {
            if (accion == DataRowAction.Add)
                btn_guardar.Text = "Agregar";
            if (accion == DataRowAction.Change)
                btn_guardar.Text = "Modificar";
            if (accion == DataRowAction.Delete)
                btn_guardar.Text = "Eliminar";
            if (accion == DataRowAction.Nothing)
                btn_guardar.Text = "Guardar";


            groupBoxControles.Enabled = accion == DataRowAction.Add || accion == DataRowAction.Change;
            PanelDerechaBotones.Enabled = accion != DataRowAction.Nothing;
            panelAbajo.Enabled = accion == DataRowAction.Nothing;
            grilla.Enabled = accion == DataRowAction.Nothing;


            if (accion == DataRowAction.Add)
            {
                textBoxId.Text = "0";
                tbSector.Text = "";
                tbClave1.Text = "";
                tbClave2.Text = "";
            }

            if (accion == DataRowAction.Add || accion == DataRowAction.Change)
            {
                tbSector.Focus();
            }

        }
```

the problem is that when the user cancels this action, the row that was selected in the grid now looks all empty. (moved empty values ​​from the controls to the grid)

I know I'm missing something, but don't know what.
appreciate if someone help me.

Cancel button code

```
private void btn_cancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            accion = DataRowAction.Nothing;
            SetEstado();
            //((DataTable)grilla.DataSource).RejectChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the cancel button is posting back and you are not rebinding?  The grid has to be rebound after every postback.

Comment: finally i solved it with a simple grid.Refresh() after reject changes of the DataSet. Thanks anyway